# How to pop out Insert -> Shapes icons in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

In Microsoft Word, is there a way to pop out "Shapes" icons, similar to the way Insert-> Clip Art works?

[image: Clip ART POP out]

Answer (score 0):

There is no pop-up that I'm aware of, but you can add Shapes to the Quick Access Toolbar so you can access no matter what ribbon you're on. To do that, just right-click on the Shapes icon and add to the Quick Access Toolbar.